# how to make your new user inputs get updated into csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, flask

```py
user_input = ['email','fname','lname','password','gender','cohort','program','ID']
        with open('users.csv','w') as inFile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(inFile, fieldnames=user_input)
            writer.writerow({'email':email,'fname': fname ,'lname':lname , 'password':password, 'gender':gender, 'cohort':cohort, 'program':program,'ID':ID})
```

the issue with this is that, everytime a new user input is entered on the webpage, the former one is discarded

Answer (score 0):

To append more data to a file to be opened, you should use 'a' mode for opening. In 'w' mode, the file is truncated first. See the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function documentation for more information.

```
# ...
user_input = ['email','fname','lname','password','gender','cohort','program','ID']
with open('users.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=user_input)
    writer.writerow({'email':email, 'fname':fname, 'lname':lname, 'password':password, 'gender':gender, 'cohort':cohort, 'program':program, 'ID':ID})
```